# how to do live stream video on browser, write a code in html for .mp4 video file?

Tags: html, angular, video-streaming, html5-video, http-live-streaming

I have tried to implement html `<video>` tag:

```
<div> <video src="some_video.mp4" width="1280px" height="720px" controls autoplay></video> </div>
```

I have to build a live streaming Video of Mp4 video, in HTML5, angular project,
how can I find this solution, please help me for this

also I referred this documentations..

https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#attr-crossorigin

Thanks in Advance..!

Comment: you have tried.. and what happened? what's the problem you are having?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.